# Multiply Input Boxes Value in PrimeNg Angular6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am using PrimeNg 6.1.5 and Angular 6. I am using PrimeNg table for displaying the data and also the table consists of three input boxes a,b and we need to multiply those values and insert into another input box.

[image]

My Code:

```
<div class="primetable" style="box-shadow: 0 1px 20px 0 rgba(69,90,100,.08);">
    <p-table [value]="student"
        [columns]="cols"
        #dt
        class="primetable"
        [paginator]="true"
        [rows]="15">
        <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
            <div>
                <input type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    pInputText
                    size="50"
                    placeholder="Search Data Here"
                    (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')"
                    style="width:auto">
            </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="header"
            let-columns>
            <tr>
                <th style="padding: 15px 15px;color: #1e6bb8;background: white"
                    *ngFor="let col of columns">{{col.header}}</th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body"
            let-student
            let-i="rowIndex"
            let-columns="columns">
            <tr [pSelectableRow]="student">
                <td >{{i+1}}</td>
                <td>{{student.regnum}}</td>
                <td>{{student.name}}</td>
                <td><input id="a" class="form-control" name="valuea" type="number" /></td>
                <td><input id="b" class="form-control" name="valueb" type="number" /></td>
                <td><input id="ab" class="form-control" name="mulvalue" type="number" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
</div>
```

Ts Code:

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/student/studentslist').subscribe(res => {
      let data = res.json();
      this.student = data;
    });

    this.cols = [
      { field: 'S.No', header: 'S.No' },
      { field: 'regnum', header: 'Regnum' },
      { field: 'name', header: 'Name' },
      { field: 'a', header: 'a' },
      { field: 'b', header: 'b' },
      { field: 'ab', header: 'a*b' },
      { field: 'Options', header: 'Options' }
  ];
  }
```

Thanks in Advance

**Edit:** After Trying @sunil singh answer this is my output:
[image]

Its Calcuting value for all the text boxes at the start of page itself and giving it as 0 but I shouldn't have any value there in A*B textbox.

**Debugging Mode:** As advised by @sunil singh I have used Debugging Mode
[image]

**Working Code:** Thanks a lot @Sunil Singh

```
<tr [pSelectableRow]="student">
                <td >{{i+1}}</td>
                <td>{{student.regnum}}</td>
                <td>{{student.name}}</td>
                <td><input id="a" #first class="form-control" name="valuea" type="number" /></td>
                <td><input id="b" #second class="form-control" name="valueb" type="number"/></td>
                <td><input id="ab" class="form-control" name="mulvalue" type="number" [value]="(first.value && second.value) ? (+first.value * +second.value) : ''" /></td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-green"
                        style="font-size: 15px;color: #1e6bb8"
                        (click)="editbutton(student)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger"
                        style="font-size: 15px;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-spin-hover"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="gotoprofile(student)"
                        style="font-size: 15px;"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-spin-hover"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ElementRef` to solve this kind of issue.

```
<td><input #first class="form-control" name="valuea" type="number" /></td>
<td><input #second class="form-control" name="valueb" type="number" /></td>
<td><input [value]="(first.value && second.value) ? (+first.value + +second.value) : ''"  class="form-control" name="mulvalue" type="number" value="" /></td>
```

### Debugging version

```
<td><input #first class="form-control" name="valuea" type="number" /> {{first.value}}</td>
<td><input #second class="form-control" name="valueb" type="number" />{{second.value}}</td>
<td><input [value]="(+first.value + +second.value)" class="form-control" name="mulvalue" type="number" value="" />{{(+first.value + +second.value)}}</td>
```

> note + is appended to convert string to int in expresion `+first.value + +second.value`

Comment: Wow Thanks a lot it's working but do u have any idea of how to do it with row-index???

Comment: You need some kind of reference to this operation. I don't see any object at row level. You bind these 3 fields with `student` and operate on it. Note : do not forget to bind through `ngModel`

Comment: Okkk but one thing is getting wrong here. When I enter A, B values for one Row A*B is going gud but A*B column for rest of the rows is getting value as 0

Comment: That should not happen. To debug this issue you can print `{{first.value}}` `{{second.value}}` in html.

Comment: Ya but its calculating for other rows too may be.... So when the calculation happens the other row input boxes has 0

Comment: I meant print the {{first.value}} {{second.value}} for all. So that you can that in action. Updated my anwer for your refence

Comment: I have updated my question please refer that @sunil singh

Comment: I got your issue now. I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: [Angular] Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{ (first.value && second.value) ? (+first.value * +second.value) : undefined }}] in @41:86

Comment: my bad. I used interpolation which was not required. use this `[value]="(first.value && second.value) ? (+first.value + +second.value) : ''" `

Comment: Bruh just a small doubt. Just assume I should save all rows data on one submit click from a datatable like above. Just give some hint of how to do that

Comment: You have `student` object for each row. Just bind one property of `user`.. Ex : `[(ngModel)] = "student.a"`. It will create new property in `user` if does not exist.

Comment: Ok bruh thanks a lot. Please can u share your mail id bruh I will msg when I have doubts. Just edit comment after I mailed u pls bruh I have many doubts.

Comment: Sorry, that is not doable. Just post into `stackoverflow` if you have any query.

Comment: Ok bruh thanks a lot anyways. Thanks for your valuable time. Is there any option atleast to chat with u when required bruh in Stack?